# How login to a Custom docker registry with SSL Cert from Windows server

Tags: windows, docker, docker-registry

I am trying to login to a private repository from a windows machine using the docker command prompt, but I cannot figure out where I am supposed to place the SSL cert on a Windows machine.

I have successfully logged in from a Linux machine by placing the cert file in ***/etc/docker/certs.d/mydomain.com:port/***

I have found in some of the documentation they are suggesting to place this .cert file in
***C:\Program Files\Docker\certs.d{my domain goes here }{port}***

But Still, I'm getting below error when I'm trying to log in
***Error response from daemon: Get `https://{my domain goes here }.com:{port No}/v2/`: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.***

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found my mistake, which is I have placed the .cert file in 
C:\Program Files\Docker\certs.d{my domain goes here }{port}.

It should be in, 
C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d{my domain goes here }{port}

(Please note that this ProgramData folder is a hidden folder)

Comment: In my current DockerDesktop installation, I had to use `%userprofile%\.docker\certs.d\<MyDomain>:<Port>` instead